# Nasal corticosteroids and hypertenstion

Tags: side-effects, blood-pressure, sinus, hypertension, corticosteroids

Can corticosteroid nasal sprays such as Nasonex (mometasone) and Rhinocort Aqua (budesonide), effect blood pressure? Do topical steroids like that enter the blood stream in such a way that they effects the whole body?

My condition: I have sinusitis and recently was diagnosed with high blood pressure (might be caused by different causes, weight, stress, etc.).

I am a bit confused, my ENT doctor says that corticosteroids don't; while my cardiologist says they do.

If you have any related studies or any hard evidence to support any of the claims please tell me and what do you think in general?